# Fiori launchpad: handle logout event with custom backend call without `attachLogoutEvent` (UI5 < 1.81)

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

So, I found that the launchpad Container API provides an option to register a logout event with returning a promise (https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ushell.services.Container%23methods/attachLogoutEvent).
Unfortunately, after the implementation I found out that the UI5 version must be 1.81 or higher for parameter `bAsync` to work. In my project, **we're at 1.78**, so no promises for me.

#### What's the problem?

I want to make a backend call in the said logout event. This doesn't work, since, as far as I understood my debugging, the launchpad destroys everything just after my logout event has "finished" (= every line of code in the event has been gone through, ignoring sub-functions). Timeouts etc. don't work, because their calls would also be after code progressing has already finished, meaning the calls are deleted.

#### What have I tried?

- Instant backend call without sub-functions → didn't work for the same reason as above.
- Infinite while-looping until the backend call is processed → stack overflow.
- While-looping with timeout/await → await not allowed in strict mode, timeout didn't work because of the above issue.

#### What do I think might work?

- Stall code progression until the backend call has been finished.
- Using a completely different method to get my logic into handling the logout (e.g. full custom logout).
- Ask here for further ideas.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve the issue with UI5 **1.78**?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have found a solution to this. It's probably not the technically nicest, but it works and the result looks clean enough. This is from a S4/HANA system, so it might not be a universal solution (e.g. it doesn't consider logging off within the left-side pane which doesn't exist in my launchpad).

#### What did I do?

Instead of attaching my individual logic to the Fiori logout-event, I created a custom logout button with my individual logic, followed by calling the SICF logout node.

#### How did I do it?

- Create a Launchpad plugin
- In `Component.js`, add a new header item with custom logout function

  ```js
  // ushellLib required from "sap/ushell/library"

  var oRenderer = ushellLib.Container.getRenderer("fiori2");
  oRenderer.addHeaderEndItem("sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeadItem", {
    id: "logoutButton",
    icon: "sap-icon://log",
    // ...
    press: [this._logout, this],
  }, true, false);
  ```

  ```js
  _logout: function() {
    this._callMyStuff();
    window.location.href = "/sap/public/bc/icf/logoff";
  },
  ```
- In `style.css`, hide the original logout button (logoutBtn) in desktop (`__list0...`) and mobile (`__list1...`) to prevent skipping my logic by logging off via default logout.

  ```css
  #__list0-7-logoutBtn {
    display: none;
  }
  #__list1-7-logoutBtn  {
    display: none;
  }
  ```

Comment: Is changing the page URL sufficient to log out? Have you tried the standard [`logout` method](https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap/ushell/services/Container-dbg.js#:~:text=this.logout%20%3D) provided by the shell container?